# RewriteRule with url params

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I know there's a thousand duplicate posts about this, but nothing has worked for me so far.

I'm trying to use a rewrite rule to transform `/articulo.html?id=friendly-url` to `/articulo/friendly-url`

This is what I've used in .htaccess without success:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^articulo/(.*)$ /articulo.html?id=$1 [L]
```

Edit:

This is the js that looks for the id param:

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;
        console.warn(sPageURL);
        console.warn(sURLVariables);

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this,

```
Options -Multiviews 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^articulo/(.*)$ articulo.html?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Nope, the result is the same. It loads articulo.html, without css and js because of the route change. The js that looks for the id param doesn't work either.

Comment: For correct loading of css and js use `<base href="domain name/">` in your  head section.

Comment: That works, but it doesn't solve the problem of the script not being able to check for id because of the url change. I suppose this is the intended way and I need to refactor the code to look for the id after the /?

Comment: How are you getting the value of id in html page?

Comment: I edited my post with the script that looks for the id.

Comment: Don't worry, I just refactored the code for the js. I just thought that wouldn't be necessary because of how I thought ReWrite worked (A mask for the real id params url). I guess it just doesn't work like that.